# Vaadin: How to navigate without reloading the page?

Tags: java, web, navigation, vaadin

I have to navigate between my components and I use a custom button like this:

```
button.addClickListener(click -> {
        UI.getCurrent().navigate(ClassToNavigate.class);
    });
```

The url does refresh in the search bar but it only shows a black page, I've to hit F5 to see the component in my parent layout.

My only fix is to add:

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().reload();
```

...which reloads the page after navigating to the URL, and that breaks the UX in my opinion, however... when using a BeforeEnterEvent on a class and using the method:

```
forwardTo(ClassToNavigate.class);
```

redirects perfectly... although I can't have BeforeEnterEvent for every menu button I have, I can't see why forwardTo() works perfectly and navigate() doesn't.

Is there a way to navigate without having to reload the page? And without using RouterLink which I can't because I'm already using a custom component.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share some more code? Obviously `UI.getCurrent().navigate(ClassToNavigate.class);` is not supposed to show a blank page. Are there any errors in the browser developer console?

Comment: Not sure what more I can share @Tazavoo, the page does kind of redirects, I see the right URL in the search bar but it doesn't load, it's blank unless I manually reload it. How do I check the developer console? I'm using vaadin 14 and it's a spring boot project

Comment: Depending on the browser, pressing `F12` or right clicking on the page and selecting `Inspect`, then going into the `Console` tab.

When the page is blank, is the constructor of `ClassToNavigate` called at all?

Comment: Found the issue, @Tazavoo. Thanks for pointing me to the console, I've seen in the HTML elements and I was using the nested layouts wrong. I had a mainview class which had childrens for logins and registering views and the link to the ClassToNavigate used the mainview as a parent that's why it showed a blank page

Comment: What version of Vaadin? What kind of browser and version?

Comment: Vaadin Flow 14, using Chrome, but other browsers gave me the same result. Turned out I was using the nested layouts wrong @BasilBourque

Comment: If you have found an answer yourself, it's fine to add your own answer. So it may help others.